# How do I select an element with multiple classes in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select all the elements that have two classes, a and b, *in that order*.

```
<element class="a b">
```

When I use $(".a + .b") I get elements with both classes in either order. I need only those elements with class = "a b" and *not* class = "b a". I have the same problem when I use javascript's getElementsByClassName.

Note: The reason I have to specify the order is that some of the divs in my document have class = "a b" and some have "b a" . . . I only want to select those with "a b". The document is not structured elegantly but that's not in my control.

Comment: The order of the classes doesn't affect the jQuery selector as far as I know.

Comment: Why would order matter in the first place?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but chances are that there are a lot of better ways to do it. Depending on the *order* of classes is not useful, nor common, and doesn't make sense overall. What is your goal? Maybe we can help you better with that.

Comment: Relying on the orders of classes is not a good idea. Least of all because your code will be very brittle and easily broken. You've not stated what your goal is, but I'm pretty sure there is a *much* better way to achieve it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is spot on. think more of `class` names as `tag` attributes with no weighted value - it either has a class or it doesnt - order is not EVER considered nor should be considered reliable.

Comment: The reason I have to specify the order is that some of the divs in my document have class = "a b" and some have "b a" . . . I only to select those with "a b". The document is not structured elegantly but I'm not in control of that.

Comment: @peacecoder in which case you should use different class names to identify the `.a.b` elements from the `.b.a` elements.

Comment: also - down voters - shame - this a valid question as `class` names are rendered in the order which they are given but selection by doesn't care. We were all novices at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those elements have no other classes, you can select them by attribute

```
$('[class="a b"]')
```

There's also the attributes-starts-with, and -ends-with selector, and the attribute-contains selector, that would pick up the elements even if they did have more classes

```
$('[class*="a b"]')
```

*note : this would also match `...class="what a bad idea"`*

Plain JS supports the attribute selectors in `querySelector[All]`

But this is a bad idea, it shouldn't matter what order the classes are in, and if it does, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An attribute list ideally should not give precendence to one value over another; in other words, the order is supposed to be unimportant, so you may have a questionable model here.

However, to answer your question, you're going to need something like regular expressions.

```
$('*').filter(function() { return /\ba\b.*\bb\b/.test(this.className); });
```

[Edit]

This is more forgiving if there's any chance of other classes between a and b. As Adaneo's answer shows, though, if you're sure there'll only ever be those two, you can just use the attribute selector, as he demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

If other classes are also involved you could use `filter()`

```
$(".a.b").filter(function(){
   return this.className.indexOf('a b')>-1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d002g7n8/1/

```
$('.a.b')

    .filter(function(){

        return this.classList[0] == 'a' && this.classList[1] == 'b';

    })
    .addClass('selection');
```

We first select the elements and then filter those which have class 'a' in the first place and class 'b' in second place.

Comment: this will work but is unnecessary complication and should not be practiced.

Comment: Thanks @BrandtSolovij. Could you explain me why it is unnecessary complication? If we had already $('.a.b') in a variable (for other purposes) isn't it a good idea to filter from it this way?

Comment: the conflation of `class selection` with `class order` is doing unnecessary work which is also unreliable. The order with which a class is represented should not be relied upon as classes can be added / removed / readded at any point in the lifespan of a view context. Specific intent should rely on immutable concepts like the 'existence of a thing' or not. Depending on what is trying to be achieved - using css selectors for  `data[]` or `aria[]` would also be more beneficial to the holistic composure of the DOM and leveraged for more specificity

Answer (score 0):

Selector $(".a + .b") is for second element with class `b` in such DOM:

```
<element class="a">
<element class="b">
```

or this:

```
<element class="a b">
<element class="a b">
```

About selector `+`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_element_pluss.asp

For your question you may use this selector with filter:

```
$('.a.b').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('class') == 'a b';
})
```